# installing a linux iso from within a university network

Tags: linux, installation, iso-image, gentoo

In order to install gentoo, I need to connect to a university wireless internet network. It requires a username and password login/authentication.

I'm wondering if anyone has any advice in terms of how to configure the internet connection.

The Gentoo installation documentation recommends the use of net-setup, pppoe, pptp, dhcp and iwconfig. I can't figure out how to configure this connection, as the only way I understand is to select the network from a list and enter in authentication data from within a browser.

Comment: To answer your question we need to know more about what the browser login you mentioned does. Is there any product name mentioned for the access solution? When you login through a browser, does the connection work outside this browser as well (a ping/wget/... from command line or access from another browser without logging in from there again)?

Comment: I am asking because I have seen setups where you are normally supposed to connect to an open (as in no WEP/WPA) wireless network and then establish a VPN connection. The open network did not route to anything but some selected websites (VPN configuration help etc.) and the VPN servers. For quick access without VPN they provided also a browser based solution that did only worked for browsing. This would probably not help much in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from a Linux live CD, like [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net) - that will give you a usable interface from which to pick a wireless network, and then open a browser to authenticate your IP Address/MAC. Then make a note of the IP address you are given.

Now when you reboot with your Gento Install CD, you can give the static configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Is your MAC address the same under Gentoo as under Windows? If so, **try authenticating in Windows, and then switching** to Gentoo. It worked for one of my friends on my university network, when he was installing Arch.

Comment: unfortunately, I have wiped the disk clean of windows (autonuked).

Answer (score 0):

If your connection require GUI/Web based login you should probably go for that.

Comment: I can't if I'm booting from an iso